# Sending custom Content-Type using HttpClient C# .Net6

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, content-type, request-headers

Hello Stackoverflow community. I hope someone here can help me!!

I'm trying to integrate with the Zoopla API that requires the post request to send the following customized content type. (I've got the certificate side of things working fine).

```
application/json;profile=http://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/v1.2/schemas/listing/list.json
```

I've tried the following approaches without any success (they all result in the following error)

```
System.FormatException: 'The format of value 'application/json;profile=http://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/v1.2/schemas/listing/list.json' is invalid.'
```

[image]

1. Initial approach was to set it within the content of the RequestMessage

   ```
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://realtime-listings-api.webservices.zpg.co.uk/sandbox/v1/listing/list"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            Content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json;profile=http://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/v1.2/schemas/listing/list.json")
        };
   ```
2. When that didn't work I tried to set it via the default headers (the `client` below is from the `ClientFactory`)

   ```
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json;profile=http://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/v1.2/schemas/listing/list.json");
   ```
3. My final attempt was to set it without validation

   ```
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json;profile=http://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/v1.2/schemas/listing/list.json");
   ```
4. I've just tried something else which unfortunately didn't work

   ```
    string header = "application/json;profile=http://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/v1.2/schemas/listing/list.json";

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(header));
   ```

I am well and truly stumped!! HELP!! :-)

Comment: Content = new StringContent("http://realtimelistings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/v1.2/schemas/listing/list.json", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") can you try ? I tried, i am not getting format exception.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this. You're absolutely right, this doesn't cause a format exception, however, the Zoopla API throws an error telling me the profile parameter is missing. {
 "error_advice": "The Content-Type header is missing the 'profile' parameter. Please supply 'profile', specifying the schema URL for the method you are calling: /sandbox/v1/listing/list",
 "error_name": "missing_profile"
}
It needs to be sent as part of the content-type :(

Comment: Chars such as : or / are not allowed in Content-Type header media-type parameters as per [HTTP/1.1 standard](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#media.type). Does Zoopla accept the values encoded?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Wondering if it's possible to override this behavior.

Comment: When did you get your zoopla api key? Is it still working?

Answer (score 1):

`Content-Type` is set on the content, not in `DefaultRequestHeaders`. You may try using `TryAddWithoutValidation` on the request content:

```
var content = new StringContent("hello");
content.Headers.ContentType = null; // zero out default content type
content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json;profile=http://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/v1.2/schemas/listing/list.json");

var client = new HttpClient(); // note: use IHttpClientFactory in non-example code
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://postman-echo.com/post", content);
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode); // OK
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
// {"args":{},"data":{},"files":{},"form":{},"headers":{"x-forwarded-proto":"https","x-forwarded-port":"443","host":"postman-echo.com","x-amzn-trace-id":"Root=1-6345b568-22cc353761f361483f2c3157","content-length":"5","content-type":"application/json;profile=http://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/v1.2/schemas/listing/list.json"},"json":null,"url":"https://postman-echo.com/post"}
```